# Chromebook. How do I know if my onResume is being called from the "emoji popup"?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji, onresume, chromebook

I have a chat app for chromebook.
I am in the chat and I press Search + Shift + Enter -> which brings up the "emoji popup"
This calls my apps "onPause" as the dialog is on top of the app.
After I select an emoji, my apps "onResume" is being called.

I was checking this:

```
 try {
            var newText = inputManager?.inputText
            if (newText != null && inputOnPause != null && newText.length > inputOnPause?.length ?: 0) {
                val new = newText.replace(inputOnPause!!, "")
                hasEmojis(new)
            } else false
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }
```

But for some reason now the "emoji" is loaded too slow so I cannot check if my onResume is being from an emoji or not.
Is there a better way to know if my onResume is called due to emoji popup dialog?
I checked my activity onIntent and Data/Action are null
So no idea from where my textview takes the text from neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're unable to determine if your onResume method is called specifically due to the emoji popup dialog, you can try an alternative approach to detect the emoji input. Instead of relying on the comparison of newText and inputOnPause to check for emoji input, you can utilize the inputManager to directly check if the input contains emoji characters.

```
try {
    val newText = inputManager?.inputText
    if (newText != null && hasEmojis(newText)) {
        // Emoji input detected
        // Handle accordingly
    } else {
        // No emoji input
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Error handling
}
```

In this code, the hasEmojis function is responsible for determining whether the input text contains any emoji characters. You can implement this function using various approaches, such as regular expressions or checking for specific Unicode ranges associated with emojis.

Comment: inputManager?.inputText is null onResume. Hence my initial problem.
Only If I delay around 1000ms -> that that gets updated. AKA , it takes a while for the chromebook/emoji popup dialog to actually "insert" my emoji.
And I wouldn't "delay" my whole onResume. I rewritten the code a bit, so that I call onResume and necessary api calls, and after I get response back from my api calls -> I check the inputManager and check the case.
The only problem is that I am also refetching my "Addressable" onResume. And ideally I wouldn't do that. I wouldn't delay that neither, as not needed for phones.

Comment: I kind of solved this, by listening to keyCodes, and I set a flag when Shift is being pressed, and if onPause is called right after, I know that it's called due to emoji Popup and hence I won't be calling my refresh Addressable onResume. a bit of a workaround, not ideal case, but I also doubt that people hold shift pressed, while minimizing/closing the app anyways. But still open to a more proper way to know this